# Continuously sending audio data over WIFI network in Android

Tags: android, audio

I'm planning on making an Android app where a user speaks in the microphone and the audio is simultaneously transmitted to other devices,over WIFI, using the same app.
I looked into how to use AndroidRecord, AndroidTrack and all but what I'm not sure is how should I transfer the audio to other devices over WIFI? What can I use to implement this?
Looked upon various sites and read about Datagram packet and socket, still all that seemed pretty confusing!
Would appreciate all help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a simple p2p architecture.

I assume you have some network knowledge.

You will need to use [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html), [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html) and a pair of streams that works with the kind of data you need to send, like [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html).

On sender side:

```
Socket s = new Socket(IP,PORT);
s.connect();
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
dos.write("hello".toByteArray());
```

Then on receiver side:

```
ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(PORT);
Socket s = ss.accept(); //This call will block execution, use separate thread
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream);
byte[] data = dis.read();
```

With this you can send and receive bytes, just use the stream that works with your data type.

Of course, once connection is established, both clients could send/write, just make the appropiate Input/Output Stream.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm guessing you've never tried this with audio over a unreliable network, have you?

Comment: Never, just pointing how to use a TCP socket to transfer data, if it implements a buffer and its not needed to be live it shouldnt work so bad right?